# How do I output this Text file into a table format using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Here is my .txt file:

```
    CH: "g@email.org", "j@email.org" 
    DL: "y@email.org", "ri@email.org" 
    KM: "b@email.org", "n@email.org" 
    CE: "tap@email.org", "k@email.org" 
    DE: "pi@email.org", "sp@email.org" 
    KL: "reedc@email.org", "be@email.org" 
    PR: "ks@email.org", "bt@email.org" 
    EC: "brn@email.org"
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
     Building | Email
     CH:       g@email.com
```

I'm pretty new to powershell please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to solve.

So, let's assume that input is in a text file called 'Buildings.txt'.  We can load it into memory like so:

```
$textFile = Get-Content .\Buildings.txt
```

Next up, we can split this file into lines by calling the `.Split()` method and giving it the overload of newline, which looks like this:

```
$Lines = $textFile.Split("`n")
$lines.Count
>8
```

Then we can simply step through each line and then split those on the colon character, `:` and finally, build up an object to send to the screen or put in a file or whathave you.

```
ForEach($l in $Lines){
    $building = $l.Split(":")[0].Trim()
    $email    = $l.Split(":")[1].Trim()
    [pscustomObject]@{
        Building = $building;
        Email = $email
    }
}
```

Running that gives us this, which is a useful format for further automation:

```
Building Email                            
-------- -----                            
CH       "g@email.org", "j@email.org"     
DL       "y@email.org", "ri@email.org"    
KM       "b@email.org", "n@email.org"     
CE       "tap@email.org", "k@email.org"   
DE       "pi@email.org", "sp@email.org"   
KL       "reedc@email.org", "be@email.org"
PR       "ks@email.org", "bt@email.org"   
EC       "brn@email.org"
```

This should get you going in the right direction.  If not, leave a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really clear on what you are after.

If this is your data, it is already a table, it's a formatting effort.

```
'
CH: "g@email.org", "j@email.org" 
DL: "y@email.org", "ri@email.org" 
KM: "b@email.org", "n@email.org" 
CE: "tap@email.org", "k@email.org" 
DE: "pi@email.org", "sp@email.org" 
KL: "reedc@email.org", "be@email.org" 
PR: "ks@email.org", "bt@email.org" 
EC: "brn@email.org"
' | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\EmailData.txt'

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.txt'
<#
# Results

CH: "g@email.org", "j@email.org" 
DL: "y@email.org", "ri@email.org" 
KM: "b@email.org", "n@email.org" 
CE: "tap@email.org", "k@email.org" 
DE: "pi@email.org", "sp@email.org" 
KL: "reedc@email.org", "be@email.org" 
PR: "ks@email.org", "bt@email.org" 
EC: "brn@email.org
#>
```

You can just read this back as a table ...

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.txt' -Delimiter ':' -Header Building, Email 
<#
# Results

Building Email                           
-------- -----                           
CH       g@email.org, "j@email.org"      
DL       y@email.org, "ri@email.org"     
KM       b@email.org, "n@email.org"      
CE       tap@email.org, "k@email.org"    
DE       pi@email.org, "sp@email.org"    
KL       reedc@email.org, "be@email.org" 
PR       ks@email.org, "bt@email.org"    
EC       brn@email.org  
#>
```

... and output it back out. Yet, that is a bit redundant

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.txt' -Delimiter ':' -Header Building, Email | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

View the raw data

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.csv'
<#
# Results

"Building","Email"
"CH","g@email.org, ""j@email.org"" "
"DL","y@email.org, ""ri@email.org"" "
"KM","b@email.org, ""n@email.org"" "
"CE","tap@email.org, ""k@email.org"" "
"DE","pi@email.org, ""sp@email.org"" "
"KL","reedc@email.org, ""be@email.org"" "
"PR","ks@email.org, ""bt@email.org"" "
"EC","brn@email.org" 
#>
```

See the table view

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.csv'
<#
# Results

Building Email                           
-------- -----                           
CH       g@email.org, "j@email.org"      
DL       y@email.org, "ri@email.org"     
KM       b@email.org, "n@email.org"      
CE       tap@email.org, "k@email.org"    
DE       pi@email.org, "sp@email.org"    
KL       reedc@email.org, "be@email.org" 
PR       ks@email.org, "bt@email.org"    
EC       brn@email.org
#>
```

If you are saying, you want the above look in a file, for say printing later, you can just output it that way.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.csv' | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\EmailData.dat'

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\EmailData.dat'
<#
# Results

Building Email                           
-------- -----                           
CH       g@email.org, "j@email.org"      
DL       y@email.org, "ri@email.org"     
KM       b@email.org, "n@email.org"      
CE       tap@email.org, "k@email.org"    
DE       pi@email.org, "sp@email.org"    
KL       reedc@email.org, "be@email.org" 
PR       ks@email.org, "bt@email.org"    
EC       brn@email.org
#>
```

The file extensions is really not important. I just did that to show I am working with all the same stuff, the same way.